# What does this message 'locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory' mean?

Tags: ubuntu, localization

Whenever I do an `apt-upgrade` on Ubuntu I get this message repeatedly. What do they mean and what needs to be done to remove them?

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an "old" error: the locale environment variables are not correctly set, so the program you are trying to use (perl? man?) is looking for translation files (i.e. files with a .po extension) in some wrong directory.

I think you can follow instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/session-language.html) to fix this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SF. This is essentially a link only answer. You should perhaps elaborate and at least summarize the linked strategy.